Does InstrB convert byte arrays to string and then search or does it use the byte array provided in VBA?
Microsoft Documentation
If you use a byte array as an input parameter does VBA cast it to a string and create its own array or does it use the one provided?
Function NextOpen (byteA() as byte,cursorByteBaseOne&) as long
    Dim nextCurlyOpen&
    nextCurlyOpen = InStrB(cursorByteBaseOne + 2, byteA, "{")
End Function

I'm trying to optimize for speed and want to know if I should search for bytes myself or let VBA do it.

You could test this by supplying a byte array which includes double-bytes which would be invalid in UTF-16. VBA (I believe, like Excel) uses UTF-16 for string encoding, so if VBA converts the byte array to a string and back to bytes, you should find this either mangles your input or throws an error.

@NeilT do you mean that if I have an array like [45,76,98,44,0 ] then converted to a string it should be unreadable but if instrb correctly finds [44,0] for a comma then it doesn't convert to string?

That's the sort of thing I meant; however, some testing suggests that the byte array is simply preserved as is. In VBA you can assign strings to byte arrays and vice versa, and if you start with an array comprising an odd number of bytes (which should be invalid as a UTF-16 string), assign that to a string and then assign the string to a new byte array, you'll find the new byte array is identical to the old one. So I don't think any "conversion" takes place behind the scenes. There might be a tiny performance hit if you pass a byte array to InStrB() but I'd be surprised if it's detectable.

Side note: suppose your byte array bytes is [ 255, 97, 0, 0 ]. Then InStrB(1, bytes, "a", vbBinaryCompare) returns 2, because "a" = [ 97, 0 ]. But if you then declare Dim str as String and set str = bytes, the expression InStr(1, str, "a") won't find the character, because it begins at an "odd" byte offset. (This feels like a bug to me - I wouldn't expect InStrB() to find the character either - but without researching UTF-16 in more detail I don't know offhand whether this scenario is possible if the original byte array is valid in UTF-16.)

@NeilT I did some more testing and using instrB on a string is consistently 5 times faster than using it on the byte version of that string at least using VBA's timer function. .059 vs .227 for 100k attempts each.

That is surprising and interesting to me. I'd recommend you post your benchmarking code and results as an answer to this question. I'd be interested to know the reason for this.

Addendum to my earlier comment: if you enter the I Ching hexagram for "Creative Heaven" (0x4dc0 or [ 192, 77 ] in Little-Endian UTF-16) followed by the letter A with a macron (0x0100 or [ 0, 1]) into, say, an Excel cell - rendering as ䷀Ā - then read that cell's value into a VBA byte array and call InStrB() to search for the character "M" (0x004d or [ 77, 0 ]), it will return 2, having found this "character" in the middle pairing of the 4-byte array [ 192, 77, 0, 1 ]. This feels like unexpected behaviour but I can't find so much as a warning in the VBA (or any other) documentation.
